# Configuration file for MIX app as OTP app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, erlang-otp, elixir-mix

I have an OTP Application (ChicagBoss actually). I'm trying to incorporate Phoenix app into it (as just casual OTP app).

I think that most of applications start, but I got error caused by lack of config file. How to provide configuration file to MIX application from outside? Especially in case when I try run it from rebar.How to provide the directory?

Comment: What does the error say? Which config file did it say was missing? Which application failed to start as a result? It's difficult to help without this kind of information.

Comment: It was Repo application (related to Ecto I think). But I saw those conifg tuples in config file. I don't know how to let mix app know about config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Erlang project you shouldn't use mix configs, but erlang configs instead. In your particular example the `boss.config` file. In `boss.config` you have a list of tuples:

```
[{app, Options}, {second_app, Options}].
```

In Erlang shell you can check the config for given application with:

```
application:get_all_env(app).
```

In mix config files you have something like:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
```

and you can check the config with:

```
Application.get_all_env(:my_app)
```

All you need to do is translate configs from Elixir to Erlang and put them inside `boss.config`. For example the Ecto adapter from above would become:

```
[...other apps...,
 {my_app, [{'Elixir.MyApp.Repo',
           [
            {adapter, 'Elixir.Ecto.Adapters.Postgres'}
           ]}]},
 ...other apps...
].
```

Just remember that `foo: "bar"` is a keyword list `[{foo, <<"bar">>}]` and module names in Elixir `Foo` are atoms in Erlang `'Elixir.Foo'`.

Second option is to use Elixir umbrella project which pulls both Chicago Boss and Phoenix. In this case you would need to translate boss configs to Elixir.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for. Dzięki!